# How do I fix the "Coordinates out of bounds" error in my code in Java?

Tags: java, coordinates, bounds

Here is what my code looks like. I am getting an error that says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.arrayIndexOutofBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!"
I do not know what this means or how to fix it, so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Assignment9 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @return
     */

    public static void removeBlue(Picture pic){
        Color cPic = pic.get(100,100);
        //remove blue color pane from image, set blue weight to 0
        int h = pic.height();
        int w = pic.width();
        System.out.println(cPic);
        //^this shows the red, green, and blue weights
        int b = cPic.getBlue();
        int r = cPic.getRed();
        int g = cPic.getGreen();
        System.out.println("r=" +r +"g="+g+"b="+b);
        pic.setColor(w, h, r, g, 0);   
        for(int x=0; x<w ; x++){
                //need to set color
                pic.setColor(w, h, r, g, 0);}

    }
    public static void drawredStripe(Picture pic){
    //draw a red vertical stripe that is 200 pixels wide through the middle of the image
        Color cPic = pic.get(100,100);
        int h = pic.height();
        int w = pic.width();
        int b = cPic.getBlue();
        int r = cPic.getRed();
        int g = cPic.getGreen();
        for(int x=0; x<h ; x++){
            for (int y = (w/2)-100; y <(w/2)+100; y++){
                //need to set color
                pic.setColor(x, y, r, 0, 0);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Picture dolphin= new Picture("dolphin_swimming.jpg");
        removeBlue(dolphin);   
        dolphin.show();
        drawredStripe(dolphin);
        dolphin.show(); 
}
}
```

Comment: What line is the error from?  Also what is w?  If w < 200 then there could be problems with negative y values.  Also you could be interchanging h and w in your code.

Comment: In `drawredstripe`, you're using `x` as a vertical coordinate and `y` as a horizontal coordinate.  That doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess it is

```
pic.setColor(w, h, r, g, 0);
```

You are iterating over x, yet not not using x in that for loop in removeBlue.

The coordinate (w,h) might be out of bounds which is what the error claims

Answer (score 0):

In your calls to `setColor`, the `x` and `y` values (the first two argments to the method call) are the coordinates.  And those coordinates must lie within the bounds set by the `Picture` you are trying to modify:

- If the width of a `Picture` is `w`, then the bounds for the `x` coordinate are `[0 ... w - 1]` inclusive.
- If the height of a `Picture` is `h`, then the bounds for the `y` coordinate are `[0 ... h - 1]` inclusive.

The "coordinates out of bounds" message says that the coordinates (i.e. the `x` and `y` values) don't lie within the respective bounds.

For example you are doing this:

```
    int h = pic.height();
    int w = pic.width();
    // ...
    pic.setColor(w, h, r, g, 0);
```

The bounds on the X axis are `0` to `w - 1`, but you are providing a `x` value of `w`.  The bounds on the Y axis are `0` to `h - 1`, but you are providing a `y` value of `h`.  (And there are other places in your code where you are making this and similar mistakes.)

---

> I do not know what this means or how to fix it, so any help is greatly appreciated.

1. Read and understand the above explanation.
2. Look at the places where you are calling `setColor` and analyse whether the `x` and `y` values you use are in bounds.
3. If necessary, change the code.
4. Test ... and repeat the previous steps as required.